# Web page floating pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to place arrows and small explanations floating over the top of my web page when they first signup to kinda teach them the basics.  I want like a tooltip with an integrated pointer/arrow but is not activated on mouseover, it is just loaded on the page when it is loaded and visible. Is there a jQuery or javascript that will do this?

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: Many tooltips are essentially just divs that popup when you mouseover a certain region. You can just take the divs and absolutely position them on the page where you want them to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need javascript for that. Some custom CSS will do just fine!
Or do you want the tooltips to (dis)appear? I mean like a some kind of a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html and can't be happier with it :)

You can also take a look [here](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/) to see different types of tooltips.